# Creating Object from Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, classcastexception

If I have a mapping like this:

```
<class name="Users" table="users">
    <id column="id" name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    ...
    <set name="types" table="types" cascade="all">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <element column="type_name" type="string" />
    </set>
</class>
```

How should the user object be created? I did this:

```
User u = new User();
u.getType().add(new Type(type_name));
getHibernateTemplate().save(u);
```

But there will be the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: Type`.
The Type class only has an integer `user_id` and string `type_name` in it with get/set.

Why doesn't it work? Where can I find documentation on saving objects with collection of elements? Thanks you so much.

Comment: Instead of saving a Type object, I just added the string to the Collection `u.getType().add(type_name)`. Experimentation works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections.html.

Change the element to:

```
<element column="type_name" type="Type" />
```

Then you can add types to the set.  Right now you have it defined as String.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Saw that doc, but was still unsure about how objects are created...